# Snakemake : SFTP on local machine

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, snakemake, pysftp

I am connected with ssh on a remote server from my local machine.
I run my Snakemake on the remote server.
**I would like to use as input of a rule, a file that is on my local machine.**
Of course, since I run my Snakemake on the server, the server become the local machine and the local machine the remote one (for Snakemake).

```
from snakemake.remote.SFTP import RemoteProvider

# I am not sure about the private key, is it the one I have on the server ?
# I have the same result with or without private_key anyway

# SFTP = RemoteProvider(port=22, username="myusername", private_key="/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa")
SFTP = RemoteProvider(port=22, username="myusername")

configfile : "config.json"

localrules: copyBclLocalToCluster

rule all:
    input:
        "copycluster.txt"

rule copyBclLocalToCluster:
    input:
        SFTP.remote("adress:path/to/filelocal.txt")
    output:
        "copycluster.txt"
    shell:
        "scp {input} {output}"

-----------------------------------------
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 26 of /path/to/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule copyBclLocalToCluster:
adress:path/to/filelocal.txt
```

> https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html
>   The remote file addresses used must be specified with the host (domain or IP address) and the absolute path to the file on the remote server. A port may be specified if the SSH daemon on the server is listening on a port other than 22, in either the RemoteProvider or in each instance of remote():

The doc says that the port shouldn't be port 22, but why ? I really would like to use it since I don't know how to configure another port and I'm not even sure to have the rights to do it.

Is it really a port issue ? Or I just don't understand how to use SFTP with Snakemake.

**What is the best way to use a file on my local machine as input of my snakemake ?**

---

### **EDIT**

It is not the port the problem, I don't even need to specify it because it is port 22.
I tried to specify the good ssh private key :

```
SFTP = RemoteProvider(port=22, username="myusername", private_key="/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa")
-----------------------------
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 26 of /path/to/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule copyBclLocalToCluster:
adress:path/to/filelocal.txt
```

If I try `sftp myusername@adress:path/to/filelocal.txt .` on my console on the server it works fine.

**Why it doesn't work inside snakemake ?**

---

### **EDIT**

When I try to use my password instead of ssh-key in `remoteProvider` I have the same error.

```
SFTP = RemoteProvider(port=22, username="myusername", password="mypassword")
--------------------------------
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 26 of /path/to/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule copyBclLocalToCluster:
adress:path/to/filelocal.txt
```

**I am sure the adress, username, password, ssh-key are correct and file exist, I can do it outside snakemake it works fine.**

---

### **EDIT**

Since `RemoteProvider` uses `pysftp`, I tried to copy the same file with `pysftp` in a `python` script.

```
import pysftp
with pysftp.Connection(adress, 
                       username="myusername",
                       private_key_pass="/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa") as sftp:
    sftp.get(path/to/filelocal.txt, /path/on/cluster/fileCOPY.txt)
```

**It works fine, so the problem come from my Snakefile for sure.**

---

### **EDIT**

`RemoteProvider` also need `ftputil`, I tried ftputil in a python script.

```
import ftputil
with ftputil.FTPHost("adress", "myusername", "mypassword") as ftp_host:
    print(getcwd())
    ftp_host.download(remote_path, local_path)
----------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 129, in _make_session
    return factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 152, in connect
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sftptest.py", line 16, in <module>
    with ftputil.FTPHost("adress", "myusername", "mypassword") as ftp_host:
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._session = self._make_session()
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ftputil/host.py", line 129, in _make_session
    return factory(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/work/username/miniconda3/envs/RNAseq_snakemake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ftputil/error.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise FTPOSError(*exc_value.args, original_exception=exc_value)
ftputil.error.FTPOSError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Debugging info: ftputil 3.2, Python 3.6.7 (linux)
```

Could it be a problem ? But I don't have this kind of error in snakemake, just missing file error. I don't understand why ftputil is not working.

Comment: It does not say that the post shouldn't be 22. It says (although the wording is not the best) that you need to specify the port if it is not 22 only. If it is 22, you do not need to specify it, as 22 is the default SFTP/SSH port.

Comment: oh right ! so the error don't come from the port

Comment: Did you confirm that `adress:path/to/filelocal.txt` exists?

Comment: Yes it does, if I do directly in console on my server `scp myusername@adress:path/to/filelocal.txt .`  it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SFTP on console you have to write

```
sftp myusername@adress:/path/to/file .
```

But in remote function of Snakemake you should delete the ":" between host and the path of the file.
I was mislead by the SFTP syntax but it was well written in the snakemake doc

```
# example from snakemake doc
SFTP.remote("example.com/path/to/file.bam")

# what I was doing badly
SFTP.remote("adress:path/to/filelocal.txt")
```

**The right command is :**

```
from snakemake.remote.SFTP import RemoteProvider
SFTP = RemoteProvider(port=22, username="myusername", password="mypassword")
rule all:
    input:
        # "/" instead of ":" between host and the path of the file
        SFTP.remote("adress/path/to/filelocal.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

So I did a quick & dirty search in the source code of Snakemake, and Snakemake makes use of `ftputil` which requires a username and password. When you do not provide a ssh-key path to Snakemake this password will default to `None`, which then gets passed to `ftputil`.

See [Snakemake source](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/master/snakemake/remote/FTP.py#L157-L185).

I agree that the default behaviour should default to something more sensible like `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: But I do provide a ssh-key path `SFTP = RemoteProvider(port=22, username="myusername", private_key="/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa")`. I edited my question yesterday to show the error when I use the right ssh key. By the way, it should be a private key right ? Because you said : 'I agree that the default behaviour should default to something more sensible like `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`' but I thought the `.pub` was for the public key, anyway, I tried with both private or public key, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to put my password instead of ssh-key and I have the same error I had at the beginning without providing any password or ssh-key : `Missing input files for rule copyBclLocalToCluster`. And I am sure the password is right.

Comment: Oh my bad, I thought you solved it by changing to the correct path (I didn't scroll down to see the error). I believe you are right on the keys part, I edited it. I have never used remoteprovider myself, so I am afraid I can't help with your problem